# Unset a variable set to an integer

Tags: python, variables

I set `dog = 2` and now I want to make `dog` equal nothing so that when I input `dog` it will not be defined. I have already tried `dog = dog` and `dog == dog` but clearly I have no idea what I'm doing as I just started using python.

Comment: What about `dog = None`?

Comment: Why does it need to be set to nothing in order to input it again?

Answer (score 2):

It's unclear what exactly you want to achieve here, but there seem do be to options:

First, you could set `dog` to be `None`. This keeps the `dog` variable defined, but overrides its value with an "empty" value, equivalent to Java's `null` or C's `NULL`:

```
>>> dog = 2
>>> dog
2
>>> dog = None
>>> dog
>>>
```

Second, if you don't even want the variable defined, you could use `del`. After deleting variable like that, accessing it will raise a `NameError`:

```
>>> dog = 2
>>> dog
2
>>> del dog
>>> dog
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'dog' is not defined
```

Answer (score 1):

you can delete dog completely or set dog to None.

```
del(dog)
```

or

```
dog=None
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it simply by deleting dog

```
del dog
```

Answer (score 1):

> so that when I input dog it will not be defined

It sounds like you think that if a variable is already defined you will not be able to override it with a new value.
That's false; as soon as you do an input the value of your variable will change

```
dog = 2
dog = input('New dog ') # dog is now set to your input
dog = 'string' # dog is now set to 'string'
```